# Nombre de función javascript dentro de la propia función

Tags: javascript

¿Es posible hacer algo parecido a esto?

common.js:

```
function miFuncion() {
    console.log(this.functionName); // Imprime por consola miFuncion o miFuncion()
}
```

Obviamente `this.functionName` no existe ni funciona, solo sirve para el ejemplo.

Comment: `console.log(miFuncion.name)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Puedes probar con esta forma.

Usando el objeto *arguments* puedes obtener el atributo *callee*.

El objeto *arguments* contiene una referencia a la funcion que esta siendo llamada actualmente.

```js
function miFuncion(){

  console.log(arguments.callee.name);

}

miFuncion();
```

Mas informacion en [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments/callee)

Comment: +1 Sencillo y directo, responde puntualmente a la pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto la W3C en sus consejos para webmasters recomienda evitar el uso de "click here" que en el caso del español se puede entender como evitar el uso de "Aqui" como texto de enlaces. Referencia: https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere

Comment: @Rubén Corregida, muchas gracias, no conocia al respecto

Answer (score 13):

`caller` esta obsoleto, lo mejor seria usar `callee()`

```js
function func1() { func2(); }

function func2() { console.log(func2.caller.name); }

func1();
```

con callee()

```js
function hola(){

  console.log(arguments.callee.name);
}

hola();
```

de forma mas nativa

```js
function obtenerNombreDeFuncion(f) {
  var res = f.toString();
  res = res.substr('function '.length);
  res = res.substr(0, res.indexOf('('));
  return res;
}
function hola(){
  }
console.log(obtenerNombreDeFuncion(hola));
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la fuente donde se declara a caller como obsoleto? En [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/caller) se incluye una nota, pero esta indica que es una función no estándar, pero eso es distinto a que sea obsoleta.

Answer (score 7):

Una forma de obtener el nombre de la función que esta siendo llamada, como quizá ya alguna respuesta lo indica, seria usando el objeto **arguments**, en el se encuentra el atributo **callee**, el cual tiene una propiedad llamada **name**, en donde esta el nombre de la función que ha sido llamada.

```js
function funcion(){
  console.log("Funcion: " + arguments.callee.name + "()");
}

funcion();
```

Otra manera, aun mas sencilla, aunque bien desconozco si es o no estándar u obsoleta es acceder a la propiedad **name** de una función, así:

```js
function funcion(){
  console.log("Funcion: " + funcion.name + "()");
}

funcion();
```

Bien, ademas del ejemplo que escribi, ahi un ejemplo mas que podriamos incluir y es el de obtener la funcion llamante, esto se haria con la siguiente linea:

```
funcion.caller.name
```

Este tiene el nombre **caller** *(supongo que por el Ingles del verbo llamar)* y  nos permite obtener el nombre de la función que llama a nuestra función, de la siguiente manera.

```js
function funcion(){

  console.log("Funcion: " + arguments.callee.name + "()");
  
  if(funcion.caller !== null){
    console.log("Llama: " + funcion.caller.name + "()");
  }
  
}

function llamar(){
  funcion();
}

llamar();
```

Espero que os sirva o complemente un poco la información ya existente.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte a la pregunta!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/name Entra dentro del standard en la versión **ES2015**

Answer (score 3):

Para completar las respuestas, me gustaría añadir una propiedad más acerca del nombre de las funciones.

Los navegadores que implementan el estándar `ES2015` pueden inferir el nombre de funciones anónimas desde su posición sintáctica:

```js
var f = function(){}

console.log(f.name)
```

El snippet anterior no funciona ya que no le hemos dado la opción de que use **`Babel/ES2015`**. Probémoslo:

```js
var f = function(){}

console.log(f.name)
```

Además la propiedad `name` es **readonly**.

```js
var obj = {
  method : function (){}
}

// obj.method.name = 'NuevoNombre'; // -> Error TypeError: \"name\" is read-only"

console.log(obj.method.name)
```

Si estamos usando la función para instanciar objetos y queremos obtener el nombre de la clase. Podemos acceder a la propiedad `constructor`:

```js
function A(){}

console.log(A.name);

var objeto = new A();

console.log(objeto.constructor.name);
```

Fuente : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/name)

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo de como saber el nombre de la clase que se esta ejecutando, usando Programacion Orientada a Objeto

```js
   function claseEjecutada(clase){
  console.log(clase.constructor.name);
}
class Personas {
    constructor(nombre, apellido) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
}
let yo = new Personas("stack", "overflow");
claseEjecutada(yo);
```